# Centering objects within UITableViewController

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uilabel, center

I have two views in a UITabbarController with tableViews that are centered perfectly using this code

```
float origenX = [self locationTable].contentSize.width * .1;
float origenY = ([[self view] frame].size.height / 2) - ([self        locationTable].contentSize.height / 2);
float sizeW = [self locationTable].contentSize.width * .8;
float sizeH = [self locationTable].contentSize.height;
CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(origenX, origenY, sizeW, sizeH);

[[self locationTable] setFrame:newFrame];
```

but in another view in the same viewController I have a label and try to space it the same way

```
float labelW = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width * .8;
float labelH = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height * .6;
float x = ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width / 2) - (labelW / 2);
float y = ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height / 2) - (labelH / 2);

[[self infoLabel] setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, labelW, labelH)];
```

Only the label is not centered correctly on the Y axis.  I have tried centered by getting sizes using

```
[[UIScreen mainScree] bounds].height /  2
[[self view] superView] bounds].height / 2
[[self view] bounds].height / 2
```

Any ideas?  Why can I easily center it with a tableView but not a label?  Thanks

Comment: is the label text alignment is center?

Comment: Does it work in some orientations and not others?  Do you have any constraints on the label which could move it after you set the frame?

Comment: Have a look at the text alignment. It is a lable. If the lable has a width of 200 but the text in it just needs 100 of it then all the text within the perfectly centered lable appears on the left side of the screen.

Comment: LithuT.V and Hermann, text alignment is center however The label background color is different so I could see if the label itself was aligned correctly.  Inafziger, I have no constraints as I'm not using auto layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you make use of

```
CGRectInset
Returns a rectangle that is smaller or larger than the source rectangle, with the same center point.
```

For example:

```
UIView *baseView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100,100)];
[baseView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
UIView *innerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(baseView.bounds, 20, 20)];
[innerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(baseView.bounds));
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(baseView.frame));
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(CGRectInset(baseView.bounds, 8, 8)));
[baseView addSubview:innerView];
[self.view addSubview:baseView];
```

UILabel inherits from UIView so you can make user of `-setCenter:` method to set the centerpoint

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, after a lot of trial and error I just could not get it to align programmatically.  I have to just place it in IB.  The tables were the ones dynamically sizing so that was crucial, but the label is always the same size so it doesn't need to move.